# Can you configure the App Inbox to retrieve inbox messages from after a certain date?

Tags: mobilepush

We are implementing the SFMC SDK in order to use MobilePush and are successfully receiving alerts and inbox messages. We have a requirement to have the ability to only retrieve messages of a certain age ex. only retrieve messages that are less than 1 month old.

**Is it possible to tell configure the SDK to do this?** Looking at the [InboxMessageManager interface](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/javadocs/MarketingCloudSdk/8.0/com.salesforce.marketingcloud.messages.inbox/-inbox-message-manager/index.html) and functions such as getMessages, getReadMessages and getUnreadMessages, I see no parameter or other option to configure the retrieval of messages after a certain date.

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin's `filter` (ref. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-filtering.html)

```
SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
  sdk.mp { push ->
    val messages = push.inboxMessageManager.messages.filter { it.startDateUtc?.after(Date("1/1/1970")) ?: true /* Add message if startDateUtc is null? */ }
  }
}
```